# How to iterate through a JSON list and retrieve needed values

Tags: javascript, json

Hey everyone

Yeah I know, there are duplicates but I'm still struggling. So, my goal is to loop through JSON list which I'm getting using external api, and extract the values that I need. The values that I need are date and avgtempC which are stored in 'weather'

List look like this:

```
{
"data":
{
    "weather":
    [
        {
            "date": "2020-04-13",
            "astronomy": [
                {
                    "sunrise": "06:29 AM",
                    "sunset": "08:22 PM",
                    "moonrise": "02:24 AM",
                    "moonset": "09:53 AM",
                    "moon_phase": "Waning Gibbous",
                    "moon_illumination": "53"
                }
            ],
            "maxtempC": "7",
            "maxtempF": "44",
            "mintempC": "4",
            "mintempF": "40",
            "avgtempC": "6",
            "avgtempF": "43",
            "totalSnow_cm": "0.0",
            "sunHour": "11.6",
            "uvIndex": "4",
            "hourly": [
                {
                    "time": "0",
                    "tempC": "8",
                    "tempF": "47",
                    "windspeedMiles": "19",
                    "windspeedKmph": "30",
                    "winddirDegree": "65",
                    "winddir16Point": "ENE",
                    "weatherCode": "122"
                }]

        },
        {
            "date": "2020-04-14",
            "astronomy": [
                {
                    "sunrise": "06:27 AM",
                    "sunset": "08:24 PM",
                    "moonrise": "03:24 AM",
                    "moonset": "10:48 AM",
                    "moon_phase": "Last Quarter",
                    "moon_illumination": "46"
                }
            ],
            "maxtempC": "11",
            "maxtempF": "52",
            "mintempC": "3",
            "mintempF": "37",
            "avgtempC": "7",
            "avgtempF": "45",
            "totalSnow_cm": "0.0",
            "sunHour": "11.6",
            "uvIndex": "5",
            "hourly": [
                {
                    "time": "0",
                    "tempC": "4",
                    "tempF": "39",
                    "windspeedMiles": "4",
                    "windspeedKmph": "6",
                    "winddirDegree": "121",
                    "winddir16Point": "ESE",
                    "weatherCode": "116"
                }]
        }]
}
}
```

I'm getting correct output when I'm accessing those values directly, like this:

```
 let forecast = response['data']['weather'][0];
 let output = `${forecast['date']} : ${forecast['avgtempC']}°C`;
```

But what I want is to loop through the list and get all the dates and temperature for each day. I tried this:

```
     for (let k in forecast) {
      if (forecast.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        output += (`[` + forecast[k] + `]` + `,`);     
      }
    }
```

and

```
    for (let k in forecast) {
        output += (`[` + forecast[k] + `]` + `,`);     
    }
```

but what I'm getting is :

```
[2020-04-13],[[object Object]],[7],[44],[4],[40],[6],[43],[0.0],[11.6],[4],[object Object]
```

and for some reason it only reads the details of the first date (2020-04-13), but not both.

I also tried

```
    for (let k in forecast) {
        output += (`[` + forecast[k].date + `]` + `,`);     
    }
```

but it returns undefined objects.
Is there anything I'm missing out or is it just the loop that's incorrect, I've spent lots of time trying to figure this out but without any luck. I would appreciate any help guys, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently looping though the attributes of the first array element (`response['data']['weather'][0]`). If you want to loop through all elements of the array you shouldn't access the first element (`[0]`). Furthermore, [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loops through object properties. You want to use [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) which loops over iterable objects (like arrays).

```js
const response = {"data":{"weather":[{"date":"2020-04-13","astronomy":[{"sunrise":"06:29 AM","sunset":"08:22 PM","moonrise":"02:24 AM","moonset":"09:53 AM","moon_phase":"Waning Gibbous","moon_illumination":"53"}],"maxtempC":"7","maxtempF":"44","mintempC":"4","mintempF":"40","avgtempC":"6","avgtempF":"43","totalSnow_cm":"0.0","sunHour":"11.6","uvIndex":"4","hourly":[{"time":"0","tempC":"8","tempF":"47","windspeedMiles":"19","windspeedKmph":"30","winddirDegree":"65","winddir16Point":"ENE","weatherCode":"122"}]},{"date":"2020-04-14","astronomy":[{"sunrise":"06:27 AM","sunset":"08:24 PM","moonrise":"03:24 AM","moonset":"10:48 AM","moon_phase":"Last Quarter","moon_illumination":"46"}],"maxtempC":"11","maxtempF":"52","mintempC":"3","mintempF":"37","avgtempC":"7","avgtempF":"45","totalSnow_cm":"0.0","sunHour":"11.6","uvIndex":"5","hourly":[{"time":"0","tempC":"4","tempF":"39","windspeedMiles":"4","windspeedKmph":"6","winddirDegree":"121","winddir16Point":"ESE","weatherCode":"116"}]}]}};

for (const forecast of response.data.weather) {
  console.log(`${forecast.date} : ${forecast.avgtempC}°C`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank a lot @3limin4t0r , I also tried to solve it myself and it actually worked, what worked was

```
    for(let i = 0; i < forecast.length; i++){
        output += (`[` + forecast[i].date + `]`); 
        output += (`[` + forecast[i].avgtempC + `]`);
    }
```

but in this case I had to change forecast to

```
let forecast = response['data']['weather'];
```